# replace space only between parentheses

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

In a string, I am trying to replace all spaces between parentheses by an underscore. For example, given `this ( is my ) simple example` I'd like to get `this (_is_my_) simple example`.

I am working on the bash and thought of creating a substitution expression for sed, however I cannot come up with a simple one line solution.

Looking forward to your help

Comment: What should happen for `this ( is ( another ) simple ) example` and `this ( is ( my ) not so simple example`?

Comment: Both good questions. For my case nested parentheses do not matter, as the data is quite well structured. I have tried a lot of unadvanced sed stuff, that did either result in nothing or all spaces being replaced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed ':l s/\(([^ )]*\)[ ]/\1_/;tl' input
```

If you have unbalanced parenthesis:

```
sed ':l s/\(([^ )]*\)[ ]\([^)]*)\)/\1_\2/;tl' input
```

Comment: This answer is quite old. But, it took me some time to fully understand this regex. Therefore, I brief clarification: The `l` (lower-case L) in `:l` and `;tl` is a arbitrary label. It could be also `a`. Right? The really nice idea is that we iterate the line and, if we are successful with `s/.../.../`, we jump back to the beginning by `:[LABEL] [REGEX];t[LABEL]`. Thus, we iterate one line as long as we have successful hits? Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
this ( is my ) simple example
$ awk 'match($0,/\([^)]+\)/) {str=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(/ /,"_",str); $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) str substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1' file
this (_is_my_) simple example
```

put the match() in a loop if the pattern can occur multiple times on a line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no nested parenthesis or broken pairs of parenthesis, the simplest way would be to use `Perl` like this:

```
perl -pe 's{(\([^\)]*\))}{($r=$1)=~s/ /_/g;$r}ge' file
```

Results:

```
this (_is_my_) simple example
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^/\n/;ta;:a;s/\n$//;t;/\n /{x;/./{x;s/\n /_\n/;ta};x;s/\n / \n/;ta};/\n(/{x;s/^/x/;x;s/\n(/(\n/;ta};/\n)/{x;s/.//;x;s/\n)/)\n/;ta};s/\n\([^ ()]*\)/\1\n/;ta' file
```

This caters for nested parens over multiple lines. It is however probably very slow.

Answer (score -1):

use a real programming language:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    inp = False
    for x in line:
        if x == '(':
            inp = True
        elif x == ')':
            inp = False
        if inp == True and x == ' ':
            sys.stdout.write('_')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(x)
```

This only handles the simplest case, but should be easy to extend to more complex cases.

```
$echo "this ( is my ) simple case"|./replace.py
$this (_is_my_) simple case
$
```

Comment: sed is turing complete, what's a real programming language?